# How do I create a Magento block that has input fields for to store values in variables?

Tags: blocks, messages, array, user, input

My code for displaying rotating messages is currently hardcoded and I have to go in and update the messages manually. I want to replace this with a new block in magento so other people can just go into magento and type some text into input fields to update the messages array without knowing how to code. How would I do this?

Comment: you have to create fields in configuration get it on frontend and display

Comment: How would I do this? Is that under the content tab?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create system.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="test_values" translate="label" sortOrder="140" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Test Values</label>
            <tab>sales_tab</tab>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="test_url_values" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="87" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Values URl</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

You can create a function for getting configuration values in your custom module's helper.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function getConfig($config_path)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $config_path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can get the configuration values to call this function in any phtml files.

```
$this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')->getConfig('section/group/field');
```